# wait for multiple volley responses in a for loop

Tags: android-volley

I am using volley singleton and add all volley request to it.

sample code of adding volley request to queue

```
MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jsObjRequest, "jreq1");
```

I have an onclick function.

```
buttonId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                     //....... here i call for asycn volley requests which get added to the queue of volleysingleton

                    }

                    // ******how to ensure all my volley requests are completed before i move to next step here.*****


                    //calling for new intent
                    Intent m = new Intent(PlaceActivity.this, Myplanshow.class);
                        m.putExtra("table_name", myplansLists.get(myplansLists.size() - 1).table_name);
                        m.putExtra("table_name_without_plan_number", myplansLists.get(myplansLists.size() - 1).place_url_name);
                        m.putExtra("changed", "no");
                        m.putExtra("plannumber", myplansLists.size());

                    //moving to new intent;
                        v.getContext().startActivity(m);

}
            });
```

Inside onclick i have a for loop which will execute multiple volley requests.

After the for loop it will start a new activity through intent.

But for my new activity to show, i need the data of all the volley requests in the for loop to be completed before, it leaves this activity and goes to new activity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My approach basically is to set up 2 int variables: successCount and errorCount that I use to monitor the volley requests. In the onResponse of each request, I increment the successCount variable, then in the onErrorResponse, I increment the errorCount. At the end, I check if the sum of both variables equals the number of requests made, if its not, the thread waits in a loop.
check this:

```
 buttonId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int successCount=0;
                int errorCount=0;
                for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                    //....... here i call for asycn volley requests which get added to the queue of volleysingleton
                    //in the onResponse of each of the volley requests, increment successCount by 1;
                    // i.e successCount++;
                    //also in onErrorResponse of each of the volley requests, increment
                    // errorCount by 1

                }

                // ******how to ensure all my volley requests are completed before i move to next step here.*****

                // wait here till all requests are finished
                while (successCount+errorCount<4)
                {
                    Log.d("Volley"," waiting");

                }

                //calling for new intent
                Intent m = new Intent(PlaceActivity.this, Myplanshow.class);
                m.putExtra("table_name", myplansLists.get(myplansLists.size() - 1).table_name);
                m.putExtra("table_name_without_plan_number", myplansLists.get(myplansLists.size() - 1).place_url_name);
                m.putExtra("changed", "no");
                m.putExtra("plannumber", myplansLists.size());

                //moving to new intent;
                v.getContext().startActivity(m);
            }
        }.run();




    }
});
```